# How to make a scaled android.graphics.Rect instance?

Tags: android, graphics, rect

I have a `Rect` instance lets call it `bounds` with a certain `left,top,right,bottom` values I would like to apply scaleX and scaleY to its width and height without changing its `centerX, centerY` How can I achieve this?

Comment: see `Rect#inset`

Comment: @pskink good hint, I will work on solution using that.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding,

One of the way would be to apply the changes as below,
(left - scaleX/2, top - scaleY/2, right + scaleX/2, bottom + scaleY/2)

Another way can be to apply the scaleX and scaleY respectively to width and height and then place the rect in the center of the view/screen.